# mhchem - adding more than two conditions/steps to reaction arrow in chemical equation

Tags: enumerate, arrows, chemistry, mhchem

`mhchem` has support for denoting reaction conditions/steps above and below the reaction arrow using the following format:

`\ce{A + B ->[text above][text below] C}`

Is there a nice way to add multiline conditions both above and below the arrow that doesn't go out of bounds, gets left-justified, and supports `\ce` inside of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to go about it is using [`stackengine`](https://ctan.org/pkg/stackengine?lang=en) package. I don't suppose you require automatic numbering offered by the enumerate environment in this case, so manual numbering will suffice.

Here I use `\stackon{anchor}{text}` and `\stackunder{anchor}{text}` as an example and proof of concept:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{stackengine}

\begin{document}
    The first reaction is \ce{A + B -> C + D}.

    % Adding multiline conditions
    A sample reaction:
    \ce{A + B ->[\stackon{2.~Add \ce{NaOH}.}{1.~Add \ce{HCl}.}][\stackunder{1.~Add \ce{HCl}.}{2.~Apply heat.}] C}

    The next reaction would then go here. \ce{A + B -> C + D}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `\ce` can still be used within the stack. The specific settings and commands to use from `stackengine` depends heavily on what you actually want to typeset.

---

There's no simple way to align the two (top + bottom) stacks together, as far as I can see. (`\mhchem` sets the alignment of the text of the arrows to be center by default.)
For now, you can just add in space manually via `\hspace`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{stackengine}

\renewcommand\stackalignment{l}
\savestack{\topcondition}{%
    \scriptstyle\stackunder{1.~Add \ce{HCl}.}{2.~Add \ce{NaOH}.}%
}
\savestack{\botcondition}{%
    \scriptstyle\stackunder{3.~Step3}{4.~Step 4}%
    \hspace{20pt}%
}

\begin{document}
    The first reaction is \ce{A + B -> C + D}.

    % Adding multiline conditions
    A sample reaction:
    \ce{A + B ->[\topcondition][\botcondition] C}

    The next reaction would then go here. \ce{A + B -> C + D}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: When there are only three steps they usually get distributed as one on top two on the bottom (as opposed to all three on the same side). Is there a way to left justify all of them regardless of whether one is in a stack or not?
(Stacks can be left justified via `\renewcommand\stackalignment{l}`, but for some reason, it only works with the stack below the arrow)

Comment: `\renewcommand\stackalignment{l}` left aligns both the top and bottom stack individually, as it should. It is `mhchem` that is centering them as a group. I'm presuming what you actually want is for the top and bottom stack to align left *as a whole*?

Comment: Yes, that's what I need. Also, when there are three steps usually one goes on top and two on the bottom, meaning that there's no need for a stack on top. Is there a better way to align that left as well other than using a half-empty stack?

Comment: There's no need for a stack at all. Just type it as it is, then add some manual `\hspace` as I mentioned before. e.g. `\ce{A + B ->[\topcondition][{3.~\ce{H2}\hspace{31pt}}] C}`.