# Left align reaction conditions above reaction arrow in chemformula

Tags: tikz-pgf, chemformula

Is it possible to write two or more left-aligned reaction conditions above or below the arrow in a non-hacky way? The chemformula manual explicitly mentions the case of having a line break in the text above the arrow but the resulting text is centered. A possible solution is described in the attached reference which is implemented in the mwe below. Chemformula uses tikz to draw the arrows.

[mhchem - adding more than two conditions/steps to reaction arrow in chemical equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/432750/mhchem-adding-more-than-two-conditions-steps-to-reaction-arrow-in-chemical-equ)

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{chemformula}

\begin{document}
    \ch{A ->[{1) Step 1\hspace{28pt} \\ 2) Longer Step 2}] B}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can use a `\parbox`. In order to make the box only as wide as needed, you may want to use `\widthof` provided by the `calc` package: `\ch{A ->[\parbox{\widthof{2) Longer Step 2}}{{1) Step 1 \\ 2) Longer Step 2}}] B}`. Would you consider this less hacky? I think the linked answers are fine. What is your question exactly?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I would consider it less hacky, because often there are more than two lines and your solution works without manually adjusting numbers or defining a vertical stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tabular`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemformula}

\begin{document}
    \ch{A ->[{\begin{tabular}{l}1) Step 1\\2) Longer Step 2\end{tabular}}] B}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. That works nicely without an additional package. A minor comment: only one "l" is needed in the tabular options.

Comment: @tosogoso: fixed. Thanks.